# Inheritance hierarchy from template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'd need to create a type erasure pattern which would allow to retrieve all the contained objects inheriting from a given base class. As far as I know, a popular type erasure like boost::any allows to retrieve an object with any_cast only if the requested and contained classes matches exactly, so it won't fit my needs.

I could solve the problem with template class which mimicks the inheritance relationship of the template argument. For example, `TemplateClass<Derived>` should be a child of `TemplateClass<Base>`, so that the following example would work:

```
// Suppose all clases have virtual destructors so that vtable and RTTI info are available

class ObjectWrapperBase {
}

template<class DataType>
class ObjectWrapperT: public ObjectWrapperBase {
public:
  ObjectWrapperBase(T* ptr): dataObjPtr(ptr){}
  DataType *dataObjPtr;
}

class Base{}
class Derived: public Base{}
class NotDerivedFromBase{}

int main(){

  std::vector<ObjectWrapperBase*> v;
  v.push_back(new ObjectWrapperT<Base>(new Base));
  v.push_back(new ObjectWrapperT<Derived>(new Derived));
  v.push_back(new ObjectWrapperT<NotDerivedFromBase>(new NotDerivedFromBase));

  // Now suppose I want to retrieve all the Base and children objects in v
  // If ObjectWrapperT<Derived> is a child of ObjectWrapperT<Base> I can write:

  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    ObjectWrapperT<Base> *wPtr = dynamic_cast<ObjectWrapperT<Base>*>(v[i]);
    if(wPtr){
      Base *basePtr = wPtr->dataObjPtr;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a pattern to achieve this behavior? Or eventually another solution?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question right, so correct me if I'm wrong - your `Derived` and `Base` are created independently from you `TemplateClass` and you don't know their inheritance structure inside of `TemplateClass`. If so I don't think you can achieve what you want as c++ type traits doesn't implement interface to get direct parent(s) of a class.

Comment: Yes, Derived and Base have no relationship with TemplateClass, which knows nothing about them. I'm also convincing myself that there's no way to obtain what I want in C++...

Comment: You can find a workaround though if you let the user of `TemplateClass` to decide of the structure of your `Derived` `Base` relationship e.g. by providing the custom trait known from `TemplateClass` that will let user to share the inheritance structure with the `TemplateClass`. But honestly I'm not sure if this is what you are really looking for. [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FjScqN7hDAEwfSBc)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do exactly what you want, but you can get something closer with templates and operators.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename D>
struct S {
    S(D *d): d{d} {}

    template<typename B, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<B, D>::value>>
    operator S<B>() {
        return {d};
    }

private:
    D *d;
};

struct B {};
struct D: B {};
struct A {};

int main() {
    S<D> sd{new D};
    S<B> sb = sd;
    // S<A> sa = sd;
}
```

If you toggle the comment to the last line, it won't compile anymore for `A` is not a base of `B`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but is not what I would like to achieve. In fact I maybe oversimplified the situation. Actually, my TemplateClass is a placeholder in a type erasure pattern, holding an instance of an object of the template argument class. TemplateClass is a child of another non-template class, call it ClassBase, and at runtime I have a pointer to ClassBase which points to a TemplateClass object belonging to a specialization of TemplateClass with unknown template parameter.    So the actual type is unknown at compile time, and then I think that no template metaprogramming technique could help.

Comment: Well, I can try to figure out a valid approach, but you should put in your question a minimal example that more or less resembles the real case. Otherwise it's impossible to say if it exists a solution.

Comment: I added an example and explained a bit the real problem I'm facing. Thanks for your interest, skypjack

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you're looking for but you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public T
{

};
```

And then instantiate it with a mother class named `Base` like this:

```
Derived<Base> object;
```

You will finally get this from `Base`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{

};
```